# Can't access some websites using their IP address

Tags: http, web

I have windows 10.

To get the IP address of some website I type `ping somewebsite.com` in cmd.

For example if I say `ping google.com`, cmd shows `Pinging google.com [216.58.206.206] with 32 bytes of data:` and some lines after that. If I type that IP provided (`216.58.206.206`), that gets me to Google.

But some websites aren't like this. For example for website `codeforces.com` I get `213.248.110.126`, but this doesn't get me to the website, instead shows some error `404 Not Found` .

Why it doesn't work and what is the best method to get IP addresses of websites in Windows 10?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some websites cannot be accessed by IP only.

Think for example, a public (free or paid) web hosting, with shared IP. If you doesn't provide a domain name (FQDN), then the server doesn't know what page needs to be served.

Think also on some "public" services, like Azure DevOps. They provide you a FQDN over a microsoft domain, but probably each DevOps repository doesn't have their own IP. If you only provides the IP, then the service doesn't know what page are you requesting.

Also, if you enter to an HTTPS page, the certificate are securing the domain name, not IP address. If you try to enter with IP only, your navigator tells you the page are not secure (Try it with Google for example).